# Sworn translation of latest obtained diploma

Tags: student-visa, translations

I need a sworn French translation of my latest diploma, but from my understanding that translation companies in the US are not "sworn" translations. How should I go about getting my diploma translated? Are there any French companies that provide this service to US customers? Are there any American companies that provide services which a French University would accept?

**From the NY French Consulate:**

> There are no sworn translators in the United States. The profession of translator is not regulated and its practice does not require any validation of professional credentials.

https://newyork.consulfrance.org/Translators

From the NY French Consulate, perhaps I could use ATA certified translators? Would this be acceptable?

**Email I received from The University of Toulouse:**

> An important clarification concerning the French translation of your documents. A sworn French translation​ is required for your latest diploma only​ (the equivalent of a Bachelor in IT or superior), all other documents can be presented in English.

**Campus France Application:**

> The original copies of your secondary school diploma, your higher education studies diploma and a certificate proving that you have successfully completed your 3th year of higher education studies. If the original documents are not in French, they must be accompanied by a sworn translation from a French consular agent of cultural services of French Embassy or a French consulate.

Comment: In some cases the consulate itself provides translations/certifications. Maybe you can also contact them. At least this was the case for me with the German consulate in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 3):

To be safe I followed the translator advice on the NY consulate's website and I used a French company based in Grenoble:

https://www.certifiedtranslationsonline.com/en/

In total for a translation of my undergrad diploma and my undergrad transcripts the total came to 143.25 euro. Seemed a little pricey, but the process was convenient and quick. Turn around was 5 business days to download the documents. They also sent the originals (included in price) internationally to the US via La Poste.

These translated documents will be needed when I register with the university in person at Université Toulouse 1 Capitole. I will update to see if everything goes successfully when I register at the University.

Comment: Sorry forgot to update everyone! Everything went smoothly!